# What is more efficient, overriding drawRect or using viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have several `UITextView`s in several `ViewController`s.  In the past, when I have a couple of instances of needing a custom drawing for a `TextView` or `Label`, etc I would just adjust the drawing in `viewWillAppear` inside the VC that owned the UI object.  This time, I will be needed several instances to be customized.

Would it be more appropriate to just create a subclassed `UITextView` and include the drawing code in `drawRect` versus having the same drawing code spread around several VC's.  I am mainly worried about performance.  Code maintainability is a secondary concern though.

To be clear, this is what I would use in drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

So after further testing, `initWithFrame` doesn't get called, but `initWithCoder` does.  I have also found that `initWithCoder` is called once and so is `drawRect`.  In my use case (a `StaticCellTableView` with the `UITextView` in a cell, what would the difference be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include those 2 lines in init or initWithCoder (In case it's a xib or storyboard) method of the subclassed UITextView.
Basically, this is just properties of the object - the don't need to run every time the UIView needs to refresh itself.

Comment: I tried to put the drawing code in `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`, but that isn't getting called.  I also tried overriding `init`, but that isn't getting called either.

Comment: How do you load the UIView? .XIB/Storyboard? If that's the case -> initWithCoder

Comment: I load it using Storyboards.  I have found that initWithCoder does work, but with testing, it is called the same amount of times as drawRect is getting called.  What would be the difference between using the two then?

Comment: drawRect called whenever the UIView needs to render itself. Lots of times it's only once, but it can be more. For example, if you want to draw something, or do some QuartzCore graphics, you will do it in the drawRect, and sometimes you will have to call setNeedsDisplay which will call drawRect again. If it's superview will call drawRect, it's subviews will call it as well.

 Remember - drawRect can be called AT LEAST once. initWithCoder is always called only once.

Comment: If you update this to reference initWithCoder, I will accept :D  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Create a ViewController baseclass, and then use that as the superclass for all your other VCs. You can then add this and other convenience methods to it and share the wealth so to speak.

In this particular case, putting it at the end of viewDidLoad would be a good place, as that is only messaged once, where viewWillAppear may be called multiple times. If you use viewdidLoad the code will be executed once.

Comment: Not all VC's will have a `TextView` and not all VC's that have a `TextView` will have the same named `TextView`.  Maybe I am misunderstanding your answer.

Comment: I find it amazing that you'd rather subclass every textview than to add a helper method to a base class, one that takes a textview as the sole parameter then does the change you want. Every single iOS app I've worked on used a BaseViewController subclass, where we put common functionality like this. YMMV

Comment: All I have to do is tell the `TextView` what class it is and that's it.  Since not all VC's will have `TextView`'s and I already have a Base class for my VC's (they all have a dynamic background view), I found it not very efficient to look to see if I have a `TextView` on a particular VC and then do the `layer.cornerRadius` adjustment.  Seems far easier to create the UITextView subclass and then just tell the object in IB what class it is.

Answer (score 0):

I would not put those lines in the view's drawRect since that's called for every refresh.  I'd recommend that you subclass UITextView and add those lines to the custom init method.